# Custom method in Registrations controller with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a defined User and I want to be able to let him confirm his account be reentering his email and names (because those have been filled by a third party).  So here is what I have:

```
def confirm_account
    if request.get?
      self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
    elsif request.put?
      self.resource = build_resource(resource_params)
      if self.resource.save 
      else
        respond_with resource
      end
    end
  end
```

And in my template I have:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => confirm_account_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put, :autocomplete => "off", :class => 'form-vertical' }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <h1> Create your Account </h1>
    <%= f.input :first_name, :label => "First Name" %>
    <%= f.input :last_name, :label => "Last Name" %>
    <%= f.input :email, :label => "Email add." %>
  <p>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Create account" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

However, when I click on the Submit button, I see in the logs the following:

```
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'myemail@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
```

Why is not letting me try to update the user?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you aren't defining it.

See how the other actions in the Devise::RegistrationsController define `resource` here:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb

Comment: But if I put build_resource, that resource is not the current user. I basically want to be able to make the User to confirm his account by putting some fields in a form, but I want to use the devise_error_messages in the template which needs the resource.

Comment: Then if you know resource has to be current_user, why don't you just put that in?

Comment: That in where? I need to use resource, otherwise the helper <%= devise_error_messages! %> won't work.

Comment: ...in the controller where you want resource to be defined.

Comment: I'm going to try edit my code, so I make my question more clear. Sorry